# How to set property in IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I want to change the value of a property in IEnumerable, but it does not change.

```cs
IEnumerable<T1> enumlist = null;
IList<T1> personList = SelectAll();

enumlist = personList.Where(p => p.propertyA.Contains(searchText));

for (int i = 0; i < enumlist.Count(); i++)
{
     enumlist .ElementAt(i).PrpertyA = "blah blah...";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't iterate through something that is in a state where it might not have been realized. Here is how it works

`IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` returns an *enumerator* object (which implements `IEnumerator`). This has a property `Current` which returns the current item, and a method `MoveNext()` which advances the enumerator on to the next item.

The interface gives no guarantee that it has been enumerated and does not expose indexers to do so. To be able to access an index of something that can be enumerated, it needs to be accessed in a specific way. Like a `foreach` loop, or using the `IEnumerable` interface directly, or through methods that have already done this and converts it in to something that supports direct indexing.

**Option 1**

```
// create a concrete List out of the Enumerbale
var list = personList.Where(p => p.propertyA.Contains(searchText)).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < enumlist.Count(); i++)
   enumlist[i].PrpertyA = "blah blah...";
```

**Option 2**

```
enumlist = personList.Where(p => p.propertyA.Contains(searchText));

// Use the iterative properties of foreach to enumerate enumlist 
foreach(var item in enumlist)
    item.PrpertyA = "blah blah...";
```

Comment: I would not say "something that ... might not have been realized" is the correct reason. When `enumlist.Count()` is called the enumeration happens. Then it happens N times more in the loop with the `enumlist.ElementAt(i)` calls. Although, yes - `.ToList()` would save a lot of computation power.

Comment: I think option 2 won't work. If enumlist is declared as an `IEnumerable`, the items in the `foreach` will be interpreted as `object`s, so `itemProperty` won't appear.

Comment: @AndreyCh yes i was in the process of filling this out, thanks for your comment

Comment: @MarianoLuisVilla i am not sure i understand your reasoning there based on the code supplied by the OP

Comment: @TheGeneral, Oh, NVM, I didn't saw the `<T>` in the `IEnumerable`'s declaration. Cheers!